# How to clear the form input fileds when user successfully submitted the form in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

i have one registration page when user renter some values ,after successfully submission the form need to be clear all the field for that i am using predefined function called reset() inside the script section ,it's not working i am unable to get where did i mistake and one more thing autocomplete="off" is also not working please help me to fix this issue.
`Register.vue`

```
<template>
<div class="main">
    <div class="container">
        <img src="../assets/sideImg.png" alt="notFound" />
        <p>Online Book Shopping</p>
        <div class="box">
            <div class="headings">
                <h5 class="signin">Login</h5>
                <h5 class="signup">signup</h5>
            </div>
            <form id="myForm"  @submit.prevent="handlesubmit">
                <div class="fullname">
                    <p>FullName</p>
                    <input type="text" class="namebox"  required v-model="FullName" autocomplete="off" pattern="[A-Za-z]{3,12}">
                </div>
                <div class="username">
                    <p>EmailID</p>
                    <input type="email" class="emailbox" required v-model="EmailID" pattern="^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$">
                </div>
                <div class="pass">
                    <p>Password</p>
                    <input :type="password_type" class="password" v-model="Password" pattern="^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!%*?&]{6,}$" required>
                    <i class="bi bi-eye-slash" id="togglePassword"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="mobile">
                    <p>MobileNumber</p>
                    <input type="tel" class="telephone" v-model="Mobile" pattern="^\d{10}$" required>
                </div>
                <button class="btn-section" @click="clear();" type="submit">Signup</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import service from '../service/User'
export default {
    name: 'Register',
    data() {
        return {
            FullName: '',
            EmailID: '',
            Password: '',
            Mobile: '',
            password_type: "password",
        }
    },
    methods: {
        togglePassword() {
            this.password_type = this.password_type === 'password' ? 'text' : 'password'
        },
        clear(){
            document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
        },
         handlesubmit() {
            let userData = {
                FullName: this.FullName,
                EmailID: this.EmailID,
                Password: this.Password,
                Mobile: this.Mobile
            }
            service.userRegister(userData).then(response => {
                // console.log("user Details", response);
                alert("user registered successfully");
                return response;
            }).catch(error => {
                alert("Invalid Email/Mobile number");
                return error;
            })
        }
    }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
@import "@/styles/Register.scss";
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

in your **HTML**

```
<form ref="myForm" @submit.prevent="handlesubmit">
```

in your `handlesubmit`, after it finishes

```
this.$refs.myForm.reset();
```

about **autocomplete**, found [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete):

*In order to provide autocompletion, user-agents might require elements to:*

1. Have a name and/or id attribute
2. Be descendants of a  element
3. The form to have a submit button

try adding a `name` or `id` to the input.

Comment: Thanks alot @fevid,it's working fine but autocomplete="off" is not working

Comment: @Sravani, updated my answer with auto complete, not sure if it would fix your issue but worth a try